# Store Key Value Pairs as List Comprehension

Tags: python

I have this function:

---

```
datapoints = 3
abc = ['a','b','c', ... 'z']
character = abc[:datapoints]

for n in character:
    values = int(askstring("Title", "Value: "))     # 1
    dat1= character.pop(0)                          # a
    dat2 = dat1 + "," + str(values)                 # a,1
    d = dat2.split(",")                             # [a,1]
    data = list((d, d))                             # [['a', '1']] 
    print(data)
```

---

unfortunately, the data gets overridden after every loop and therefore I get this:

---

```
[['a', '1'],['a', '1']]
[['b', '2'],['b', '2']]
[['c', '3'],['c', '3']]
```

---

instead of this:

---

```
[['A', 1],['B', 2]],['C', 3]]
```

---

I have tried also list(zip(d, d)), but that doesn't help at all:

```
[('a', 'a'),('1', '1')]
[('b', 'b'),('2', '2')]
[('c', 'c'),('3', '3')]
```

---

Thank you for any help

Comment: Hi @User9023.  Why you are specifying 'd' twice while creating the final list?  And also, this [ ['A', 1], ['B', 2] ], ['C', 3] ] has unbalanced square brackets.  Could you please correct that?

Comment: @Venkat_The_Mufasa yes, you are right, list((d)) returns just ['a', '1'], I dont know how to extend the list with the new input from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your loop is overriding the values of `data` and `d` every time, you want to put `data = []` at the beginning of the loop and `data.append(d)` in the middle of the loop. Example:

```
data = []
for n in character:
    d = ...
    data.append(d)
```

2. Your loop is popping characters from `character` *and* looping over the list. You want to do either:

```
for n in character:
    dat1 = n
```

Or:

```
while character:
    dat1 = character.pop(0)
```